# Работа с реляционной БД ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Есть два таблицы: таблица новостей и таблица картинок. В таблице картинок есть поле `NewsId` которое связано с `Id` новостей.

Вот модель:

```
public class RelNewsDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NewsImageDto> NewsImages { get; set; }
}

public class NewsImageDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageItem { get; set; }
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
}
```

Я не могу разобраться, как добавлять картинки в коллекцию `NewsImages`

Вот, что происходить во View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RelNewsCreate", "News", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <h4>Title</h4>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", autocomplete = "off" })
    <br />
    <h4>Images</h4>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.NewsImages, new { type = "file", name = "uploadImage", min = "1", max = "9999", multiple = "true" })
    <br />
    <h4>Article</h4>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, 20, 0, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", autocomplete = "off" })
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-save" />
}
```

Вот, что происходит в контроллере:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RelNewsCreate(BLL.Model.RelNewsViewModelItem item)
    {
        BLL.Providers.RelNewsBdProvider dbProv = new BLL.Providers.RelNewsBdProvider();

        for (var i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var image = Request.Files[i];


            if (image != null)
            {
                byte[] imageData = null;
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream))
                {
                    imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(image.ContentLength);
                    item.NewsImages.Add(new BLL.Model.NewsImageViewModelItem { NewsId = item.Id, ImageItem = imageData });
                }
            }


          } 
        dbProv.Add(item);
        return RedirectToAction("RelNews");
    }
```

Business Logic Layer:

```
    public void Add(RelNewsViewModelItem newsItem)
    {
        dbProv.Add(MapDtoToDb(newsItem));
    }    

    public RelNewsDto MapDtoToDb(RelNewsViewModelItem dbItem)
    {
        if (dbItem != null)
        {
            return new RelNewsDto
            {
                Id = dbItem.Id,
                Title = dbItem.Title,
                Body = dbItem.Body,
                NewsImages = dbItem.NewsImages.Select(MapNewsImageDto).ToList()
            };
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Data Access Layer:

```
    public void Add(RelNewsDto newsItem)
    {
        using (var db = new DataBaseDataContext())
        {
            db.NewsVs.InsertOnSubmit(MapDtoToDb(newsItem));
            var images = newsItem.NewsImages.Select(x => new NewsImage() { Id = x.Id, ImageItem = x.ImageItem, NewsId = newsItem.Id }).ToList();
            db.NewsImages.InsertAllOnSubmit(images);
            db.SubmitChanges();    
        }
    } 

    public NewsV MapDtoToDb (RelNewsDto dbItem)
    {
        if (dbItem != null)
        {
            return new NewsV
            {
                Id = dbItem.Id,
                Title = dbItem.Title,
                Body = dbItem.Body
            };
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Доходит до последней строчки (`db.SubmitChanges();`) и выдает exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in >System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY 
>   constraint "FK_NewsImage_NewsV". The conflict occurred in
>   database "Schedule", table "dbo.NewsV", column 'Id'.

Не понимаю, как исправить ошибку.

Comment: О архитектуре. Вы хотите сделать структуру в базе под хранение массива байт или хотите хранить в БД только имя файла, а файл на диске? О самом задании. Я не понимаю, с чем у вас затык при выполнении задачи. С тем, чтобы сохранить данные, пришедшие из POST, с тем, чтобы считать данные из БД в ваши Dto'шки или что?

Comment: А зачем? Пришёл POST - сохранили картинки в базу, сделали редирект на какую-то другую страницу. Если нужно будет показать -- считали из базы.

Comment: Похоже у меня в голове два вопроса смешались. )) Я только на смежную тему отвечал и думал, что это один и тот же автор.

Comment: @AK У меня сайт если слои Data Access Layer и Business Logic Layer. Я получаю картинки в контроллер и отправляю их в Business Logic с помощью цикла, а вот как из Business Logic конвертировать картинки и отправить в Data Access я не могу разобраться.

Comment: Ок, не можете разобраться. Показывайте тогда (дописывайте код в вопрос) что у вас в BL и DAL есть из кода. У вас там видимо репозиторий есть с CRUD, непонятно не видя кода понять, где у вас затык. Пишите код, не бойтесь! Я получаю картинки в контроллер - приписали код, отправляю их в BL - приписали код, так пока не дойдёте до места затыка. Код в вопросе очень поможет лучше понять, чем ваши объяснения "там у меня есть такой-то код, а там такой-то". Сразу пишите код, будет нагляднее. У нас же тут не соревнование по телепатии, верно?

Comment: @AK добавил код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибки больше нет.

```
public void Add(RelNewsDto newsItem)
{
    using (var db = new DataBaseDataContext())
    {
        var item = MapDtoToDb(newsItem);

        var images = newsItem.NewsImages.Select(MapNewsImage).ToList();

        db.NewsVs.InsertOnSubmit(item);
        item.NewsImages.AddRange(images);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```